# How can I prevent nested UITableView moves?

Tags: ios, swift

I have following view hierarchy:

```
UITableView(A)
--UIViewController.view
----UITableView(B)
--UIViewController.view
----UITableView
```

When tableViewB scroll to the bottom, tableViewA moves(see first gif).

Question1: Anyone can explain why A moves, and how UIScrollView does it?

Question2: How can I prevent this without disable A's **isScrollEnable** or **bounces**, like the second gif?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1:Since A is above B, A handles the sliding event first, so A scrolls. The corresponding B response event is intercepted.If you still don't understand, you can Google the iOS response chain to find out.

2:For the effect you want，the most convenient way is disable A's isScrollEnable or bounces, which make A cannot handle the enent.Of course, other methods that prevent A from responding to this event can also be used，here is an example：
A USES a custom Tableview and adds the following two methods in.m

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

if ([self isPanBackAction:gestureRecognizer]) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;

}

- (BOOL)isPanBackAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

if (self.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer) {

        CGPoint velocity = [self.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.panGestureRecognizer.view];
        if(velocity.y>0){

            return YES;
        }
    }
}else if(self.contentOffset.y >= self.contentSize.height-self.bounds.size.width){
    
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.panGestureRecognizer) {
        CGPoint velocity = [self.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.panGestureRecognizer.view];
        if(velocity.y <0){
       
            return YES;
        }
    }
    
}
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it is a response chain problem. UIScrollView has a private method _attemptToDragParent:forNewBounds:oldBounds: , it change parent's contentOffset directly. When I replace it's implement, and do nothing, everything goes right.